# Fail2ban regex not matching after site moved behind load balancer

Tags: linux, nginx, security, regex, fail2ban

I installed fail2ban with nginx and it's working untill i moved it behind load balancer. Bcoz after moving behind load balancer i found there is 2 IP's showing in Logs.I want that fail2ban detect first IP and block it according to the rule.
The following is a sample log entry:

```
46.229.168.138, 64.252.86.102 - - [08/Jul/2020:10:55:08 +0530] "GET /telangana/%E0%B0%B0%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%B7%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%9F%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%B0%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%B2%E0%B1%8B-%E0%B0%85%E0%B0%A6%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%AD%E0%B1%81%E0%B0%A4%E0%B0%AE%E0%B1%88%E0%B0%A8-%E0%B0%AE%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%B0/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18082 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"
```

My fail2ban filter is :

```
[Definition]
failregex = <HOST> - - .*(POST|GET) .* HTTP.* 403 .*$
ignoreregex =
```

And My fail2ban jail is :

```
[httpd-forbidden]
enabled = true
filter = httpd-forbidden
logpath = /var/log/nginx/example.com_custom.access.log
bantime = 1800
findtime = 300
maxretry = 50
port = 80,443
banaction = iptables-multiport
```

Please help to correct fail2ban regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your case if the first ip is the one needing a ban

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>,.*"(POST|HEAD|GET|PUT).*HTTP.*" 403 .*$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andre Bezuidenhout. It work's great..

Comment: awesome glad I could help

Comment: Why the `,` (comma) after the `<HOST>`? I think the comma is not needed. And can somebody explain what/when the `"` (double quote) is need?